The following errors were detected during validation. - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
I have asp.net core mvc view, where I show input values in foreach
Here is code for view
<div class="modal-body box-wrap">
  <form role="form" novalidate class="form-validation" name="ServicePriceInformationsForm">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ServiceId" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="required-label">@L("Location")</label>
      <select class="form-control" required asp-for="LocationId">
        <option value="">@L("SelectALocation")</option>
        @if (Model.LocationId.HasValue)
        {
        <option selected value="@Model.LocationId">@Model.LocationName</option>
        }
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="required-label">@L("MaterialUom")</label>
      <select class="form-control" asp-for="MaterialUomId" id="ServicePrice_MaterialUomId">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        @if (Model.MaterialUomId > 0)
        {
        <option value="@Model.MaterialUomId">@Model.MaterialUomName</option>
        }
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>@L("Cost")</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Cost" data-rule-number="true" data-rule-min="0" data-rule-max="@AppConsts.MaxDecimalDatabaseLength">
    </div>
    @{
    int i = 0;
    }
    @foreach (var tier in @Model.LocationServicePrices)
    {
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>@tier.PricingTierName</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="@tier.PricePerUnit" name="LocationServicePrices[@i].PricePerUnit" data-rule-number="true" data-rule-min="0" data-rule-max="@AppConsts.MaxDecimalDatabaseLength">
    </div>
    i++;
    }
  </form>
</div>

Then in JS I pass data to BE like this
 this.save = function() {
   if (!_$form.valid()) {
     _$form.showValidateMessage();
     return;
   }

   var servicePrice = _$form.serializeFormToObject();
   console.log(servicePrice);


   _modalManager.setBusy(true);
   _serviceService.editLocationService(servicePrice).done(function() {
     abp.notify.info('Saved successfully.');
     _modalManager.close();
     abp.event.trigger('app.createOrEditServicePriceModalSaved');
   }).always(function() {
     _modalManager.setBusy(false);
   });
 };

The console in browser shows this

Here is model at BE
public class LocationServiceEditDto: EntityDto<int?>
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }    
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }    
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }    
    public int? MaterialUomId { get; set; }    
    public string MaterialUomName { get; set; }    
    public string LocationName => Location?.Name;    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public  LocationNameDto Location { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<LocationServicePriceDto> LocationServicePrices { get; set; }
}

Here is controller
public async Task EditLocationService(LocationServiceEditDto input)
{
    var locationServices = new List<LocationServicePrice>();
    if (input.LocationServicePrices.Count > 0)
    {
        locationServices = input.LocationServicePrices.Select(x => new LocationServicePrice()
        {
            LocationServiceId = x.LocationServiceId,
            PricingTierId = x.PricingTierId,
            PricePerUnit = x.PricePerUnit
        }).ToList();
    }
    await _locationServiceRepository.InsertOrUpdateAndGetIdAsync(new LocationService
    {
        Id = input.Id ?? 0,
        ServiceId = input.ServiceId,
        LocationId = input.LocationId,
        Cost = input.Cost,
        UnitOfMeasureId = input.MaterialUomId,
        LocationServicePrices = locationServices
     });
}

The JSON that is generated is:
{
    "Id": "",
    "ServiceId": "2031",
    "LocationId": "2",
    "MaterialUomId": "6",
    "Cost": "123",
    "LocationServicePrices": {
        "0.PricePerUnit": "1",
        "1.PricePerUnit": "2",
        "2.PricePerUnit": "3",
        "3.PricePerUnit": "4",
        "4.PricePerUnit": "5"
    } 
}

When I click save I get this error

How I can fix this?

What does your controller look like and what's in console.log(servicePrice);

@EugeneSukh Your LocationServicePrices has to be an array  of type LocationServicePriceDto . I can see that in your JSON screenshot, it is not an array. Once you generate the correct JSON as per your LocationServiceEditDto class then you would be successfully able to deserialize it.

Why it needs to be an array? @RahulSharma

You are using ICollection<LocationServicePriceDto> so when you send your JSON data, you need to deserialize against this collection

tried using var servicePrice = _$form.serialize(); instead of ~var servicePrice = _$form.serializeFormToObject();~?

as @RahulSharma said you are expected to pass an array and you are passing an object. Using this code currently? serializeFormToObject](https://gist.github.com/SergSlon/4f988ce91782f592f437)

$.fn.serializeFormToObject = function () {         var $form = $(this);         var fields = $form.find('[disabled]');         fields.prop('disabled', false);         var json = $form.serializeJSON();         fields.prop('disabled', true);         return json;     };
No method looks like this @codeandcloud

I tried to use public LocationServicePriceDto[] LocationServicePrices { get; set; } and I have same error @RahulSharma

@EugeneSukh Please post your JSON string here. Screenshots are usually not of much help in code problems.

{     "Id": "",     "ServiceId": "2031",     "LocationId": "2",     "MaterialUomId": "6",     "Cost": "123",     "LocationServicePrices": {         "0.PricePerUnit": "1",         "1.PricePerUnit": "2",         "2.PricePerUnit": "3",         "3.PricePerUnit": "4",         "4.PricePerUnit": "5"     } }
@RahulSharma

@EugeneSukh  From the looks of it, the above JSON is technically correct but it won't solve your problem because I am assuming that LocationServicePrices will have more than 4 entries so it has to be dynamic enough to handle this. Try serializing your JSON to make LocationServicePrices into an array. As per @codeandcloud suggestion try changing this line var json = $form.serializeJSON(); to var json = $form.serialize();

The correct json should be: {      "Id": "",      "ServiceId": "2031",      "LocationId": "2",      "MaterialUomId": "6",      "Cost": "123",      "LocationServicePrices": [         { "PricePerUnit": "1"},         { "PricePerUnit": "2"},         {"PricePerUnit": "3"},          {"PricePerUnit": "4"},          {"PricePerUnit": "5" }      ]     }, pls test it by hard coding and share what is your serializeFormToObject, it is not build-in jquery function.

THe problem is with the serialization.
A simple workaround will be to make to make the object as array like this.
var servicePrice = _$form.serializeFormToObject();
servicePrice.LocationServicePrices = 
         Object.values(servicePrice.LocationServicePrices)
        .map(elm => +elm);
console.log(servicePrice);

P.S: Based on assumption that LocationServicePrices expects an int array(from the screenshot of the error message).
